# rails - adding JavaScript function to form field not saving filed value in database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I wrote a rails form and it was working fine until I added a javascript to it. This javascript sums field values enter by user and saves them in a total field so user don't have to manually total it.

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function findTotal(){
    console.log("this is working")
      var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
      var tot=0;
      for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
              tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
      }
      document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
  }
</script>
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :student_id,label: "Admission Number of Student" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :tuition_fee , onblur: "findTotal()", id: "qty1", name: "qty" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :fine, onblur: "findTotal()", id: "qty2", name: "qty" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :previous_books, onblur: "findTotal()", id: "qty3", name: "qty" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :annual_fund, onblur: "findTotal()", id: "qty4", name: "qty" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :total, name: "total",  id: "total" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit  class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now when I fill the form, the function works fine and submitting button creates record as well but all the values entered in these number fields are not stored in the database and it shows nil. If I remove it from number fields, these work fine. Any idea what I am doing wrong? thanks.
EDIT:
here are my params:

```
   private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_payment
      @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:student_id, :section_id, :year, :month, :date, :payment_mode, :tuition_fee, :fine, :previous_books, :annual_fund, :total)
    end
end
```

and relevant controller method:

```
  def create
    @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
    @payment.student_id = Student.find_by_admission_number(@payment.student_id).id
    @payment.section_id = Student.find(@payment.student_id).section_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_payment_path, notice: 'Payment Record was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Could you post up the params and the controller action as well please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overriding the  'name'  attributes. They should be like, for example: `name="payment[fines]"`. So, when you do submit, it generates the following object:

```
Parameters=> { payment => { fines: value} }
```

That is spected in your controller (payment_params)